# Can we merge the four [multiple-monitors] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently four tags related to having multiple displays connected to a single PC.

[multiple-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) (*340 questions*)

> Handling multiple monitors connected to a machine at the same time, regardless of their number and view configuration. For a more specific case of only two monitors with view area expanded to the second one, use [dual-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor).

[dual-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) (*226 questions*)

> Dual-monitor is the use of two physical display devices in order to increase the area available for computer programs running on a single computer system. Use this tag if your question involves errors while programming using a dual monitor setup and not if it is concerned with the hardware prospects

[multiscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiscreen) (*143 questions*)

> multiscreen refers to development of software able to utilize multiple physical displays.

[multi-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor) (*116 questions*)

> The use of multiple physical display devices, such as monitors, televisions, and projectors, in order to increase the area available for computer programs running on a single computer system.

I can't think of any specific issues which would need one tag over the other.

**Is there any particular reason not to combine these tags together?**

Comment: Alternate titles: "How many [monitors] do we need?" and "Isn't four [monitors] a bit excessive?"

Comment: Site hooked up 4 [monitors], you won't believe what happened next!

Comment: Is having more than a monitor something a programmer is interested to answer? Is this even programming?

Comment: @Braiam possibly what is needed to get a program to effectively take advantage of all of a users monitors.

Comment: @JoeW but what concrete knowledge you need to answer that kind of questions? Is there a book about programming on multiple monitors? A chapter?

Comment: @Braiam Does there need to be a book/chapter for someone to have the knowledge to write the code to take advantage of multiple monitors?

Comment: I don't see any reason these would all be separate tags either, seems like it just fragments answers

Comment: @JoeW I don't know. How would you learn to take advantages of multiple monitors if that isn't documented anywhere or worse, there's nothing on the tools you use for programming that is relevant to such tasks.

Comment: @Braiam Well there have been programs for a while that where written to with the purpose of multi monitor support. The easy example being all the programs to improve multi monitor support on windows. So there has to be documentation about the features out there somewhere.

Comment: @Braiam There's at least a [section of MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on programming for multiple monitors. It comes up [in Raymond Chen's blog](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multiple+monitors+site%3Ablogs.msdn.microsoft.com+inurl%3Aoldnewthing&t=palemoon&ia=web) occasionally. I think that one could conceivably be an expert in how to program correctly for utilizing multiple monitors, particularly related to a particular platform.

Comment: @JoeW Again, is that something you can specialize in? As in you being an expert?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. isn't C#, .Net or whatever kids use these days enough for tagging those questions?

Comment: Fun fact: most of users that answered questions on those tags, have the nice number of just 1 answer, and hello Hans.

Comment: @Braiam Why couldn't someone be an expert in multi monitor programming? Multiple monitor setups are becoming more common these days which would mean there is an increased need to support them.

Comment: @JoeW I think you missed my fun fact comment: "Why couldn't someone be an expert in multi monitor programming?" Because there's concrete evidence that there are not.

Comment: @Braiam because the tag is not that popular?

Comment: @JoeW Lack of popularity is not a valid reason for deleting a tag. I have email alerts set up for the Dolphin Emulator on Super User and Arqade, as I used to be a developer on the project. There are only around 30 questions under the tag, but only means it's even harder to find good answers to those questions.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I think you are misunderstanding, I am not arguing for deleting the tag.

Comment: I am absolutely an expert in multi-monitor programming on the Windows platform. (Although I think that is a very oversimplified metric for assessing the usefulness of a tag.)

Comment: Okay, it looks like [[tag:multiscreen]] may have something special to do with Android development, as I see that tag used with [[tag:android]] a *lot*, and very few of those questions seem to actually be about multiple monitors. Rather, they are about different devices with different screen resolutions. Maybe we can get an Android developer to weigh in about whether this tag is actually ready for a merge?

Comment: @Braiam I'd take a guess that a multiple monitors tag might be useful for glitches arising from multiple monitors, e.g., when I do a certain thing with my old laptop's system configuration, I get a phantom VGA adapter that causes [inexplicable drawing glitches in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnvvh.png).

Comment: @jrh and in what way that has any relevance to actual programming? I mean, show me someone which only expertise is doing exactly that?!

Comment: @Braiam It only happens on certain kinds of programs and specific kinds of controls, it's a programming problem, in the form of "why are cursor artifacts showing up in front of my TreeView, but only if I have multiple monitors". As far an expert on "just this", SO also has a git tag, but I kind of doubt that anyone is an expert in just git (and no coding languages whatsoever), being familiar with the video card related win32 / WPF drawing routines for multiple monitors that might combine to cause the glitch is a valid area of expertise.

Comment: Though FWIW I can't think of many cases for where the "multiple monitors" tag would really be all that more useful than just having "...with multiple monitors" in the question title or body, I was mostly just guessing at why somebody made it, not saying I'm defending it or saying it should stay in. I doubt anybody would want to follow a multiple monitors tag, but in theory it might be a good search filter?

Comment: @jrh "It only happens on certain kinds of programs and specific kinds of controls" then why not having tags for those instead? I'm having a hard time looking for anything coherent or rational with this.

Comment: @Braiam if the root cause is a win32 TreeViews and multiple monitors, maybe I can see a [multiple monitors] tag, but I agree it's a stretch and that's why I don't really support this tag. It would really only be useful if somebody had a problem that only showed with multiple monitors and they wanted to see everything known to mess up with that on a particular program, though Google is pretty good at that already. E.g., if you search "Visual Studio Windows 7 Multiple Monitors", I'm pretty sure Google would do most of the "tagging" work for you and try to pull up the most relevant set of posts.

Comment: @Braiam we have an internal application at our company that **always** opens new windows on the primary screen rather than the screen that the original window was location.  Seems that programming it so it doesn;'t do that might be a programming problem, which would be applicable.

Comment: @psubsee2003 well, the language, library, whatever you are using to do that seems like an *actual tag*. Just because I want to program a goat simulator I don't use [tag:goat] [tag:simulator]... Tags are supposed to be *concrete and unambiguous*, you can't have that with something that a) isn't a programming concept universal to most context, like string and function b) that other more specific tags capture the meaning better than this one does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following merges have been done and corresponding synonym mappings have been created:

- [multiple-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) ← [dual-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor)
- [multiple-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) ← [dual-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitors)
- [multiple-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) ← [multi-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor)

I first went through all of the questions in these tags to verify that a merge was appropriate. I agreed that it was. Only one or two retags were necessary, and those were just cases where the tags were used incorrectly in the first place.

I also closed and deleted a fair number of old, off-topic questions hiding under these tags—stuff that should have been asked on Super User, Ask Ubuntu, Ask Different, or some such place, but wasn't. Too bad, so sad.

<sup>Don't worry, no useful answers were lost during the deletion. Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311431/kde-dual-screens-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-mouse-to-another-screen), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313468/appropriate-screen-recording-software), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084828/error-concerning-ubuntu-one-app), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090407/cloning-lg-plasm-tv-to-a-long-distance), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158555/mac-book-2011-el-capitan-os-x-can-i-have-2-monitors-connected-to-the-mdp), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269495/one-powerpoint-presentation-over-multiple-monitors), etc. I did keep one closed question that had good answers, but I'm not linking it here, so hah!</sup>

I also caught [a recommendation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289184/best-toolkit-for-multi-monitor-program) or two.

I was going to manually merge the tag wikis from the orphaned tags into the master tag, but that turned out not to really be necessary. Those tag wikis were terrible. The best one was just a paragraph plagiarized from Wikipedia. So I wrote a new excerpt for the newly-minted master tag. The full tag wiki is still [awaiting your brilliant insights](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multiple-monitors/info)!

---

**NOTE:** I did not touch [multiscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiscreen) yet, since it looked like that tag might have a unique meaning when it comes to Android development. Very few of the questions with that tag are actually about multiple monitors—rather, they are about different devices with different screen resolutions. Maybe we can get an Android developer to weigh in about whether this tag is actually ready for a merge?

Answer (score -4):

This tag shouldn't even exist. If there are languages, libraries or methods for programmers to do this stuff, why don't just have tags for *those things* instead?

Is like telling someone that wants to eat apples to get a bag of fruits that may or may not contain apples. Why not using apples when we want apples, orange for oranges, etc. instead of having a tag called fruits and leaving answerers to figure out whenever or not the fruits they want would ever appear!

Lets look at the related tags:

- c# × 124
- windows × 93
- java × 72
- winapi × 55
- wpf × 49
- c++ × 46
- .net × 46
- winforms × 37
- swing × 37
- fullscreen × 35
- javascript × 26
- osx × 26
- windows-7 × 22
- delphi × 21
- screen × 19
- python × 18
- linux × 18
- monitor × 18
- vb.net × 13
- visual-studio × 13
- visual-studio-2010 × 13
- window × 13
- jframe × 12
- mouse × 10

I don't see any tag that seems to be a technology or tool specifically meant for dealing with multiple monitors... I count several languages, a pair of IDE, OS's, couple libraries and frameworks but all of them do much, *much* more than simply dealing with monitors. Aren't we wasting an opportunity here? If I were Cody and expert on ["multi-monitor programming on the Windows platform"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355598/can-we-merge-the-four-multiple-monitors-tags?noredirect=1#comment507662_355598) what should be the tag I need to follow to get exactly that? I see that the most popular are windows related (C#, Windows itself, Winapi), but Cody would also get stuff that is certainly not his expertise...

Am I missing something obvious here or the tags were not even consistently used to mean something specific? I mean, more specific that "X monitors".

Comment: Already **-5** and no comments... I love this!

Comment: @maxkoryukov I'm not sure what were you expecting.